# Why does my G1X lower the shutter speed, irrespective of shutter priority mode?

Tags: sports, shutter-priority, canon-g1-x

From time to time I have to use my Canon G1X for indoor sport (basketball) photos.

Often the light isn't really much so I've tried to fix the shutter speed using the shutter priority mode (Tv), the idea is to let the camera compensate with ISO and aperture having the shutter fast enough to *freeze* the players.

I can accept dark RAW images in order to manipulate the exposure in post processing.

I've noticed though the **the camera does not respect the settings!** even if I select let's say 1/500" it drops the speed down to 1/30" is necessary.

Automatic ISO are also limited to 1600 even if you can manually select an higher value (with noise).

Does anybody know if there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have "Safety Shift" enabled?

Comment: Yes! you are right I didn't catch it 'cause of a poor Italian translation

Comment: @MichaelClark please rewrite your precious comment as an answer an I will "officially"  accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have "Safety Shift" enabled the camera will behave as you describe. To stop the camera from changing the shutter speed when there isn't enough light please disable "Safety Shift."